# Preventing WinSCP from unselecting files after a drag and drop from local folder to remote folder

Tags: windows-7, winscp

Is there any way to prevent WinSCP from unselecting files after a drag and drop from local folder to remote folder?

Example:

[image]

I use WinSCP 5.7.6 with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

(FileZilla doesn't unselect files after a drag and drop from local folder to remote folder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. WinSCP always unselects files as they are being processed.